Unable to connect to Google Cloud SQL PostgreSQL instance (private IP) using Go SQL Connector: iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken permission denied
I am trying to connect to a PostgreSQL database instance in Google Cloud (with a private IP connection) using the SQL Connector library in Go. However, I am encountering the following error:
ERROR Failed to dial instance {"error": "failed to get instance: Refresh error: failed to get instance metadata (connection name = \"<connection-string>\"): Get \"https://sqladmin.googleapis.com/sql/v1beta4/projects/\/instances/postgres/connectSettings?alt=json&prettyPrint=false\": compute: Received 403 `Unable to generate access token; IAM returned 403 Forbidden: Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken' denied on resource (or it may not exist).
This error could be caused by a missing IAM policy binding on the target IAM service account.
For more information, refer to the Workload Identity documentation:

Environment Details:
Google Cloud: PostgreSQL instance with private IP connection enabled
Service Account Permissions:

Cloud SQL Admin
Cloud SQL Client
Compute Network Admin
Project IAM Admin
Service Account Admin
Service Account Token Creator
Storage Admin
Workload Identity User

Go Environment: Running the code in a VM instance that is part of the GKE cluster in the same VPC.
Here’s the relevant portion of my Go code:
func connectDB() error {
    user := "postgres"
    password := "password"
    connectionName := "connectionName"
    sslmode := "require"
    dbName := "databaseName"

    config, err := pgx.ParseConfig(connStr)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    opts := append([]cloudsqlconn.Option{},
        cloudsqlconn.WithDefaultDialOptions(cloudsqlconn.WithPrivateIP()),
    )

    d, err := cloudsqlconn.NewDialer(context.Background(), opts...)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    config.DialFunc = func(ctx context.Context, network, instance string) (net.Conn, error) {
        log.FromContext(ctx).Info(fmt.Sprintf("Dialing instance: %s", instance))
        conn, err := d.Dial(ctx, connectionName)
        if err != nil {
            log.FromContext(ctx).Error(err, "Failed to dial instance")
        }
        return conn, err
    }

    dbURI := stdlib.RegisterConnConfig(config)
    dbPool, err := sql.Open("pgx", dbURI)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }   

    err = dbPool.Ping()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }   
    return nil
}


Troubleshooting Attempts:
Verified that the database instance has a private IP and is reachable within the same VPC.
Checked and ensured that the service account has the following permissions:
Cloud SQL Admin
Cloud SQL Client
Service Account Token Creator
Workload Identity User, among others.
Ensured that the Go application is running inside a VM that has access to the private VPC.

Are you using workload identity? Recommended way is workload identity https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/workload-identity

Also are you following this documentation? https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-instance-kubernetes#go_1

@danyL yes I am using the workload identity and using the documentation only.

I wonder if you need to gran the VM service account the Service Account Token Creator role instead of the Workload Identity service account.

This may also be useful: https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Developer-Tools/iam-serviceAccounts-getAccessToken-Permission-Denied-on-Billing/m-p/787183/highlight/true#M2633

Notice this part of the error you linked: "Permission 'iam.serviceAccounts.getAccessToken' denied on resource (or it may not exist)". The only two roles that you mentioned that have that particular permissions are

Service Account Token Creator
Workload Identity User

In the documentation, only workload identity user is mentioned, so I would to try to troubleshoot where that role is mentioned:

Follow this best practice if you did not
Make sure you complete all the steps as per the doc. Tips: make sure you complete all the required steps, 1 to 6 ( from namespace creation to policy to impersonation to annotation). For step 5, do you get


The member name must include the namespace and Kubernetes ServiceAccount name. For example, serviceAccount:example-project.svc.id.goog[example-namespace/example-serviceaccount].

Other troubleshooting steps you can take for Workload Identity Federation for GKE
Check step 5 (Check that the IAM service account is configured correctly)
gcloud iam service-accounts get-iam-policy \
GSA_NAME@GSA_PROJECT.iam.gserviceaccount.com

Expected:
  - members:
  - serviceAccount:PROJECT_ID.svc.id.goog[NAMESPACE/KSA_NAME]
  role: roles/iam.workloadIdentityUser

